# Automatic jquery scrollTo navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

> http://jsbin.com/ifutav/2/edit

I want to use http://balupton.github.com/jquery-scrollto/demo/ to automatically scroll relative navigation links. With the code below this is the error I'm getting: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/article/` which is obviously caused by the slashes (which are a required namespace from a ajax plugin), when I remove them the error goes away but still does not work: http: //jsbin.com/ifutav/3/edit but the `e.preventDefault()` does. So obviously two errors are happening here:

1. jQuery doesn't like the `href` value
2. scrollTo isn't working correctly

## HTML: links

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/item-1/">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/item-2/">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/item-3/">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/item-4/">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

## HTML: elements

```
<section id="/item-1/"></section>
<section id="/item-2/"></section>
<section id="/item-3/"></section>
<section id="/item-4/"></section>
```

## Javascript

```
$('nav ul li a[href^="#"]').each(function() {

  // store values so it doesn't have to execute onclick
  var $this = $(this),
      value = $this.attr('href'),
      element = $(value);

  $this.click(function(e) {

    // prevent default scrolling
    e.preventDefault();

    // scrollTo element
    element.scrollTo();
  });
});
```

I don't know the reason behind either of these areas but I assume they are some kind of type error? idk...

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:  1) Remove the forward slashes from your href and id's.  2)  If you are using http://balupton.github.com/jquery-scrollto/demo/ then the method ScrollTo needs a capital S: `element.ScrollTo();`

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dBh3W/

Comment: thanks, but still I need the slashes for an ajax framework as I had mentioned, is there anyway they could be removed and then hardcoded in?

Comment: I just tried putting the slashes back in my jsfiddle and it worked fine... so maybe your only problem was the lowercase ScrollTo.  If you are getting some other javascript error, please post it.